# What exactly can you put after #if 0?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

According to the C language standard, the lines between `#if 0` and `#endif` are required only to contain preprocessing tokens, so most kinds of completely malformed syntax e.g. `#foo` or `#include [bar]` are allowed (silently ignored); GCC and Microsoft C++ do indeed silently ignore such.

An `@` does not as far as I can see correspond to any preprocessing token so should still be a syntax error. GCC and Microsoft C++ silently ignore it. Is this effectively a language extension or am I missing something?

Does anyone actually use the ability to put malformed syntax between `#if 0` and `#endif` in practice?

Comment: I don't see anything in the spec limiting what goes between those. Could you point it out?

Comment: is `#define foo @` illegal?

Comment: It's ignored by compiler as preprocesor cuts out everything between #if 0 and #endif

Comment: @chris, the source file is split into pp-tokens before preprocessor is run, see [lex.phases]/3. Hence, even stuff between `#if 0/#endif` must consist of valid pp-tokens.

Comment: @chris: In the 6.10 of C99, the grammar of the `#if` is said to contain a `group` and a `group` is a sequence of `group-part` which may be `text-line` and a `text-line` is a sequence of `preprocessing-token`.

Comment: @rodrigo, That would seem to do it.

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, the standard does not state what happens when something cannot be made into a preprocessing token, so it is undefined behaviour, and thus all compilers are fine.

Comment: @rodrigo: If you go one step further, you see that `preprocessing-token` includes "each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above" (C99 6.4/1; C++98 2.4)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Your comment answers the question, I think you should post it as an answer. A comment, though: while that does cover @, other characters, such as ", could still cause problems, because the behaviour for a " that does not form a string literal is explicitly undefined.

Comment: @hvd: And indeed GCC 4.7.2 emits a warning for such a case: `warning: missing terminating " character`.

Comment: @rodrigo It's not always as friendly as a warning, though. Older versions of GCC implemented multi-line string literals as an extension (a permitted extension), so might cause the `#endif` to be treated as part of a string.

Comment: @hvd: The "" in `#include "foo.h"`, which isn't a string literal, certainly is well-defined. I'm confident that's allowed in a `#if 0... #endif`  block.

Comment: @MSalters You're right, but that wasn't the point I was trying to make. Similarly, `'"'` is perfectly valid, as is `/* " */`. Corrected version: the behaviour for a " that is a preprocessing token by itself is explicitly undefined. I was thinking of `#if 0` / `"` / `#endif`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both the C and C++ standard contain a special 'escape clause' in their grammar that makes that every non-white-space character is (part of) a preprocessing token. For this reason, whatever you put in a block between `#if 0` and `#endif` can almost never cause a compilation error. The only exception are mismatched quotes for character and string literals.

And yes, I regularly put malformed syntax between `#if 0` and `#endif` to disable some partially-written code.

Comment: Note what @hvd said -- you can still get undefined behavior for unmatched quotes for example.

Comment: Unless, of course, it happens to contain mismatched preprocessing directives or unclosed comments...

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor is what is sounds like: It processes files before (pre) the compiler. The input the actual compiler sees is what the preprocessor feeds it, and if a part of the code is between `#if 0` and a matching `#endif`, then the compiler won't even see that code. That is why you can put almost anything in that section, the compiler will simply not see it.

Answer (score 2):

Code between #if 0 and #endif is not going to include in final source code (after per-processor output). If you are using Visual Studio and want to see pre-processor's output,
Go to project property -> Select C/C++ -> Select Preprocessor -> Select 'Yes' in Preprocess to a file option.

Go to your project directory and you will see '.i' file. This is your preprocessor's output.

And you can see code between #if 0 and #endif is not included. So no question of error.